# upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

For some reason, I am getting this error whenever I am running a query on my server. On my local setup, this query takes around 7-8 seconds to return, but it keeps timing out on my actual server.

Errors:

```
2014/03/26 13:40:13 [error] 11084#0: *22 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxxxx, server: xxxx request: "GET /xxxxx/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///srv/www/poka/app/poka/nginx/poka.sock", host: "xxxx"
2014/03/26 13:41:26 [error] 11084#0: *80 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxxxx, server: xxx, request: "GET /xxxxx/?format=json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///srv/www/poka/app/poka/nginx/poka.sock", host: "xxxx.$
```

I am running Django/Nginx/uWSGI.

Here is my nginx conf:

```
# poka  _nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///srv/www/poka/app/poka/nginx/poka.sock; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  443;

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/xxx/xxx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/xxx/xxx.key;


    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xxxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 750M;   # adjust to taste

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /srv/www/poka/app/poka/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

and here is my uWSGI conf:

```
master          = true
processes   = 2
socket          = /srv/www/poka/app/poka/nginx/poka.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true

pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid # create a pidfile
harakiri = 120 # respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
max-requests = 5000 # respawn processes after serving 5000 requests
log-maxsize = 10000000
post-buffering=4096
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/poka.log # background the process & log
```

Comment: Can you please let know the solution to this.